# Speed of light violation?

Tags: speed-of-light, astrophysics, pulsars

While reading this article [Discovery of the companions of millisecond pulsars](http://phys.org/news/2015-09-discovery-companions-millisecond-pulsars.html), it mentions a pulsar rotating multiple times a second, and I was wondering if this doesn't exceed the speed of light?

Comment: Have you attempted to calculate whether this is so?

Comment: No no, I am too much a layman for that, that is why I am asking the experts here.

Comment: How are you supposing that it exceeds the speed of light?

Comment: I was assuming that the surface of the pulsar spinning at that rate would exceed the speed of light. I don't have the math background to calculate it, thus the question here.

Comment: @DirkBruere 's answer shows the correct approach. You use basic geometry to find out what you want - the circumference slips past a given point, say, 1000 times a second.

Comment: Comments about votes, be they up or down are neither attempts to improve the questions, not generally a good idea from the point of view of maintaining a positive culture. Personal epithets, however, are far over the line and will not be tolerated. New users are encouraged to take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour) and pay particular attention to the information on the kinds of question that [should](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [should not be asked](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Typical ballpark figure for the diameter of a pulsar is 10km. Therefore circumference is Pi multiplied by the diameter, which is about 30km. If it is rotating at (say) 1000 revolutions per second (for a millisecond pulsar) we get a velocity of 30,000 km/s or about 10% the speed of light

Comment: I'm so glad someone else thought to ask this question! I was wondering the same thing recently. So is 10% of c fast enough for any interesting relativistic effects? 
I guess time always runs slower in the tropics, right?